# CPP creating variable for calculating position*velocity covariance

Tags: c++

I am using CPP to create an matrix for my covariance of an x,y,z position by an x,y,z velocity. This is my first time using CPP for this so I am looking for some helpful insight.

Scenario:
I'm creating a testing app for a drone in flight, the drone will send constant feedback with x-pos, y-pos, z-pos and x-vel, y-vel, z-vel. I then need to calculate the covariance of these numbers together and output in binary64[6][6] type.

Should I use a double[6][6] array? or would it be better to use a <vector<vector> ?

Answer (score 0):

Size is fixed to `8x8`.

I suppose you want to pass it to functions and return it from functions.

Thats neither a `double[6][6]` (cannot return from function) nor a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` (variable size) but a

```
std::array< std::array< double,6 > , 6>
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Can you explain a little bit on why this is the best approach?